# Check if on correct dispatch queue in Swift 3

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift3

I have a few unit tests in which I'd like to test if a callback is called on the correct dispatch queue.

In Swift 2, I compared the label of the current queue to my test queue. However in Swift 3 the `DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL` constant no longer exists.

I did find the `dispatch_assert_queue` function. Which seems to be what I need, but I'm not sure how to call it.

My Swift 2 code:

```
let testQueueLabel = "com.example.my-test-queue"
let testQueue = dispatch_queue_create(testQueueLabel, nil)

let currentQueueLabel = String(UTF8String: dispatch_queue_get_label(DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL))!
XCTAssertEqual(currentQueueLabel, testQueueLabel, "callback should be called on specified queue")
```

---

**Update:**

I got confused by the lack of autocomplete, but it is possible to use `__dispatch_assert_queue`:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  __dispatch_assert_queue(test1Queue)
}
```

While this does work for unit tests, it annoyingly stops the whole process with a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` instead of only failing a test.

Comment: Why not set a precondition to test directly for the queue or set "specific" on it and retrieve it later?

Comment: Could you not use setSpecific and getSpecific? src: https://github.com/duemunk/Async/blob/feature/Swift_3.0/AsyncTest/AsyncTests.swift

Comment: @KFDoom Didn't know about those functions. That works great for these unit tests!

Comment: Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54869129/308315

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Based on [KFDoom's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952262/check-if-on-correct-dispatch-queue-in-swift-3#comment63354897_37952262), I'm now using `setSpecific` and `getSpecific`.

This creates a key, sets it on the test queue, and later on, gets it again:

```
let testQueueLabel = "com.example.my-test-queue"
let testQueue = DispatchQueue(label: testQueueLabel, attributes: [])
let testQueueKey = DispatchSpecificKey<Void>()

testQueue.setSpecific(key: testQueueKey, value: ())

// ... later on, to test:

XCTAssertNotNil(DispatchQueue.getSpecific(key: testQueueKey), "callback should be called on specified queue")
```

Note that there's no value associated with the key (its type is `Void`), I'm only interested in the existence of the specific, not in it's value.

**Important!**
Make sure to keep a reference to the key, or cleanup after you're done using it. Otherwise a newly created key could use the same memory address, leading to weird behaviour. See: http://tom.lokhorst.eu/2018/02/leaky-abstractions-in-swift-with-dispatchqueue

Answer (score 40):

Use [`dispatchPrecondition(.onQueue(expectedQueue))`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1780605-dispatchprecondition), the Swift 3 API replacement for the `dispatch_assert_queue()` C API.

This was covered in the WWDC 2016 GCD session (21:00, Slide 128):
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/

Comment: This requires macOS 10.12/iOS 10.0, is that correct? – Can this be used in a unit test?

Comment: correct.It will terminate the process if the precondition fails, as long as you can handle that in your unit test it will work for that purpose

Answer (score 7):

Tests based on [KFDoom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37954135/2083655):

```
import XCTest
import Dispatch

class TestQueue: XCTestCase {

    func testWithSpecificKey() {
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "label")

        let key = DispatchSpecificKey<Void>()
        queue.setSpecific(key:key, value:())

        let expectation1 = expectation(withDescription: "main")
        let expectation2 = expectation(withDescription: "queue")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if (DispatchQueue.getSpecific(key: key) == nil) {
                expectation1.fulfill()
            }
        }

        queue.async {
            if (DispatchQueue.getSpecific(key: key) != nil) {
                expectation2.fulfill()
            }
        }

        waitForExpectations(withTimeout: 1, handler: nil)
    }

    func testWithPrecondition() {
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "label")

        let expectation1 = expectation(withDescription: "main")
        let expectation2 = expectation(withDescription: "queue")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            dispatchPrecondition(condition: .notOnQueue(queue))
            expectation1.fulfill()
        }

        queue.async {
            dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(queue))
            expectation2.fulfill()
        }

        waitForExpectations(withTimeout: 1, handler: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: `setSpecific(key:,value:)` is not needed in the second case.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to set a precondition to test directly for the queue or set "specific" on it and retrieve it later. Further, one could use setSpecific and getSpecific. Alternatively, you can use a precondition check if you're on a queue so that should fulfill the "get current" need. src: https://github.com/duemunk/Async/blob/feature/Swift_3.0/AsyncTest/AsyncTests.swift

and

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Dispatch/Dispatch.swift

Comment: the first link is now broken.

Answer (score 1):

One related option is to set a Main Queue / UI Queue precondition:

```
dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(DispatchQueue.main))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
/*
Dispatch queue and NSOperations in Swift 3 Xcode 8
*/

protocol Container {

    associatedtype ItemType
    var count: Int { get }
    mutating func pop()
    mutating func push(item: ItemType)
    mutating func append(item: ItemType)
    subscript(i: Int) -> ItemType { get }
}

//Generic Function
struct GenericStack<Element> : Container {
    mutating internal func push(item: Element) {
        items.append(item)
    }

    mutating internal func pop() {
        items.removeLast()
    }

    var items = [ItemType]()
    internal subscript(i: Int) -> Element {
        return items[i]
    }

    mutating internal func append(item: Element) {
        self.push(item: item)
    }

    internal var count: Int { return items.count }
    typealias ItemType = Element
}

var myGenericStack = GenericStack<String>()
myGenericStack.append(item: "Narendra")
myGenericStack.append(item: "Bade")
myGenericStack.count
myGenericStack.pop()
myGenericStack.count

//Some NSOperation
class ExploreOperationAndThread {

    func performOperation() {

        //Create queue
        let queue = OperationQueue()
        let operation1 = BlockOperation {
            var count = myGenericStack.count
            while  count > 0 {
                myGenericStack.pop()
                count -= 1
            }
        }

        operation1.completionBlock = {
            print("Operation 1")
        }

        let operation2 = BlockOperation {
            var count = 0
            while  count == 10 {
                myGenericStack.append(item: "ItemAdded")
                count += 1
            }
        }

        operation2.completionBlock = {
            print("Operation 2")
            print(myGenericStack.items)
        }

        //Suppose operation 3 is related to UI

        let operation3 = BlockOperation {
            //run on main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(myGenericStack.items.count)
            }
        }

        operation3.completionBlock = {
            print("Operation 3")
            print(myGenericStack.items.count)
        }
        //add operation into queue
        queue.addOperation(operation3)
        queue.addOperation(operation1)
        queue.addOperation(operation2)
        //Limit number of concurrent operation in queue
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        //add dependancies
        operation1.addDependency(operation2)
        operation2.addDependency(operation3)

        if myGenericStack.items.count == 0 {
            //remove dependency
            operation1.removeDependency(operation2)
        }
    }
}

//Other ways of using queues
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    ExploreOperationAndThread().performOperation()
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("I am performing operation on main theread asynchronously")
}

OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
    var count = 0
    while  count == 10 {
        myGenericStack.append(item: "Narendra")
        count += 1
    }
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5 , execute: {
    ExploreOperationAndThread().performOperation()
})

let queue2 = DispatchQueue(label: "queue2") //Default is serial queue
queue2.async {
    print("asynchronously")
}
```