# How to get the current queue name in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

We have function like this in swift 2.2 for printing a log message with the current running thread:

```
func MyLog(_ message: String) {
    if Thread.isMainThread {
        print("[MyLog]", message)
    } else {
        let queuename = String(UTF8String: dispatch_queue_get_label(DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL))! // Error: Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'DispatchQueue?'
        print("[MyLog] [\(queuename)]", message)
    }
}
```

These code no longer compile in swift 3.0. How do we obtain the queue name now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if on correct dispatch queue in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952262/check-if-on-correct-dispatch-queue-in-swift-3)

Comment: Now [`DispatchQueue` has `label` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1780825-label).

Comment: @Eonil: That should be posted as an *answer.*

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. I posted it.

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58738439/12394554

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Now DispatchQueue has label property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1780825-label).

> The label you assigned to the dispatch queue at creation time.

```
var label: String { get }
```

---

It seems been existed from first, maybe not been exposed via public API.

```
macOS 10.10+
```

And please use this only to obtain human-readable labels. Not to identify each GCDQ.

If you want to check whether your code is running on certain GCDQ, you can use [dispatchPrecondition(...) function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952262/check-if-on-correct-dispatch-queue-in-swift-3/37962147#37962147).

Comment: @yuchen-zhong Does this answer the question? I know this can be helpful, but there's still no more way to get the current queue.

Comment: @Klaas Getting AFAIK, "getting current queue object" is prohibited and a strongly discouraged practice. I think there are several underlying intentions...

Comment: I know, but the OP asked for it. Is there any reason to not use it for debugging purposes? (I'm aware of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1780605-dispatchprecondition)

Answer (score 56):

As **Brent Royal-Gordon** mentioned in his [message](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20160613/002280.html) on **lists.swift.org** it's a hole in the current design, but you can use this horrible workaround.

```
func currentQueueName() -> String? {
    let name = __dispatch_queue_get_label(nil)
    return String(cString: name, encoding: .utf8)
}
```

Comment: Just tried the solution, But its taking extra time, like 1-2 second to execute single line. Isn't it..??

Answer (score 8):

If you don't like unsafe pointers and c-strings, there is another, safe solution:

```
if let currentQueueLabel = OperationQueue.current?.underlyingQueue?.label {
    print(currentQueueLabel)
    // Do something...
}
```

I don't know any cases when the `currentQueueLabel` will be `nil`.

Comment: If the queue is not created by ourselves, what will the label be? And have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952262 Is it related? @kelin

Comment: 1. Label will be something like "com.apple.main-thread".
2. It's about testing and it's quite related, but there are no direct answer for your question.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work correctly. For the same queue, `OperationQueue.current?.underlyingQueue?.label` returns "com.apple.main-thread", while `String(cString: __dispatch_queue_get_label(nil), encoding: .utf8)` returns  "myDispatchQueueLabel"

Comment: In Xcode 9 and iOS 11, finding this doesn't work. Preferring `__dispatch_queue_get_label(nil)`

Comment: According to Apple docs, if you're not currently in the context of an Operation, then `current` will pretty much certainly return nil.

Comment: @jakehawken, I tried it. I just put `print(OperationQueue.current)` inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and the `current` wasn't nil. It was like: `<NSOperationQueue: 0x14cd38dd0>{name = 'NSOperationQueue Main Queue'}`. So, probably everything is inside the context of some Operation.

Comment: @kelin I'm pleasantly surprised to hear that! I was basing my statement off of Apple's documentation. I'm glad to hear this though. Good to know!

Comment: This only works for dispatch queues that were created specifically for operation queues and furthermore, will only trigger if those dispatch queues are currently active because their operation queue is actively performing an operation.  If either of those conditions are not met, you will get a `nil` label.  Case in point: your own dispatch queues, or your during your own block submitted to any queue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a wrapper class that offers some safety (revised [from here](https://gist.github.com/khanlou/2dc012e356fd372ecba845752d9a938a)):

```
import Foundation

/// DispatchQueue wrapper that acts as a reentrant to a synchronous queue;
/// so callers to the `sync` function will check if they are on the current
/// queue and avoid deadlocking the queue (e.g. by executing another queue
/// dispatch call). Instead, it will just execute the given code in place.
public final class SafeSyncQueue {

    public init(label: String, attributes: DispatchQueue.Attributes) {
        self.queue = DispatchQueue(label: label, attributes: attributes)
        self.queueKey = DispatchSpecificKey<QueueIdentity>()
        self.queue.setSpecific(key: self.queueKey, value: QueueIdentity(label: self.queue.label))
    }

    // MARK: - API

    /// Note: this will execute without the specified flags if it's on the current queue already
    public func sync<T>(flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags? = nil, execute work: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        if self.currentQueueIdentity?.label == self.queue.label {
            return try work()
        } else if let flags = flags {
            return try self.queue.sync(flags: flags, execute: work)
        } else {
            return try self.queue.sync(execute: work)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Private Structs

    private struct QueueIdentity {
        let label: String
    }

    // MARK: - Private Properties

    private let queue: DispatchQueue
    private let queueKey: DispatchSpecificKey<QueueIdentity>

    private var currentQueueIdentity: QueueIdentity? {
        return DispatchQueue.getSpecific(key: self.queueKey)
    }

}
```

Comment: In general it is not safe to create a DispatchSpecificKey as an instance variable. Keys are compared by their address in memory, if you create and free multiple keys, they might end up sharing the same pointer. See my post on this issue: http://tom.lokhorst.eu/2018/02/leaky-abstractions-in-swift-with-dispatchqueue

Comment: Interesting, thanks @TomLokhorst! Guessing a static constant would be preferred here since they are thread safe

Answer (score 0):

This works best for me:

```swift
/// The name/description of the current queue (Operation or Dispatch), if that can be found. Else, the name/description of the thread.
public func queueName() -> String {
    if let currentOperationQueue = OperationQueue.current {
        if let currentDispatchQueue = currentOperationQueue.underlyingQueue {
            return "dispatch queue: \(currentDispatchQueue.label.nonEmpty ?? currentDispatchQueue.description)"
        }
        else {
            return "operation queue: \(currentOperationQueue.name?.nonEmpty ?? currentOperationQueue.description)"
        }
    }
    else {
        let currentThread = Thread.current
        return "UNKNOWN QUEUE on thread: \(currentThread.name?.nonEmpty ?? currentThread.description)"
    }
}



public extension String {

    /// Returns this string if it is not empty, else `nil`.
    public var nonEmpty: String? {
        if self.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
        else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will work for both `OperationQueue` and `DispatchQueue`.

```
func printCurrnetQueueName()
{
    print(Thread.current.name!)
}
```